# 「cookie」の名前の由来とは？

Tags: cookie, 専門用語

自動ログインからユーザーの分析にまで幅広く使われることになった cookie ですがそもそもなぜ cookie という名前なんでしょうか？

最初にこの cookie という単語を知った時、「ブラウザが何かモリモリたべるものなのかな？」と思って
それから数年間たったいまもこの単語の由来を知りません

javascript とか Ajax とかそういうものにはある程度単語からテクノロジーを推測できるものもあるんですがこの cookie だけは単語から連想するのが個人的には食べ物の「クッキー」です。

調べたところ「マジック・クッキー」という単語が由来にありそうなのですが、この「マジック・クッキー」そのものも単語の出処が不詳な謎の単語らしいです。

> 3. クッキー
>
> 「クッキー」とは、ウェブサイトを訪れた時、コンピューターに一時的に保存される情報のことである。この言葉は、元々同じ意味を持つ「マジック・クッキー」というIT用語を省略したものからきているが、「マジック・クッキー」自体の言葉の由来は定かではない。一説によると、「マジック・クッキー」を手に入れないと先に進めないというテレビゲームが昔あり、そこが発祥なのではないかと言われている。
>
> 出典 | [意外に知らない『IT用語』の由来7選 「ブログ」「スパム」「クッキー」など](http://rocketnews24.com/2014/03/18/423428/)

なぜ cookie という名前になったのか、その由来を知っているかたはいませんか？

Comment: 元記事のRocket Newsはむちゃくちゃですね。Hackerの項も「ヤサグレ馬」ってことになってますけど、そのhackは同音異義語。hackは何かを切ることで、元々はノミで家具を作るような職人がhackerだそうです。この記事全体を信用しないほうがいいでしょう。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi  ほんとだ。たしかに「hack」は「柵をナタとかでぶっこわす」という感じの意味だったはずなんですが間違ってますね

Comment: ゲーム由来説は[ここ](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472661)にありました。Ben Bucknerによる説明はあちこちにコピペされて広まっている様子。でも確証はありませんね。

Comment: Ben Bucknerの説明ですが、少なくとも"Adventure"にはcookieは出てきませんね(今ソースをgrepしました)。時期については、X11のMIT-MAGIC-COOKIEが90年前後なので80年代後半からあったのは確かだと思いますが。

Answer (score 5):

[このウィキペディアの記事](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Origin_of_the_name)によると、「cookie」の名前の由来は[フォーチュン・クッキー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC)のことにあるようです。フォーチュン・クッキーは、[Kenji](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7837/kenji-noguchi)さんが説明した通りで、クッキーの中にメッセージが入っていると同じように、「cookie」は特別なメッセージ（データ）が入っているのですね。

また、[ルー・モントゥリ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A5%E3%83%AA)さんの[ブログの記事によると](http://www.montulli-blog.com/2013/05/the-reasoning-behind-web-cookies.html)、[昔のクッキー](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic-cookie.html)のことを思い出してから、（また、そもそもルーさんは[クッキー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC)が好きなようですから）「cookie」という名を選んだようです。

Comment: なるほど〜。名前に歴史ありですね。

Comment: ちなみに[こちらの記事](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/F/fortune-cookie.html)によるとfortune cookieと言うのはUnixでログイン時に(稀にログアウト時に)表示されるランダムメッセージのことだそうです。([fortune (UNIX)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(UNIX)))ちなみに「一説」に該当する記事は全く見つけられませんでした。典拠もなしに紹介されている場合、記事著者(またはその周辺の人)の創作かも知れません。

Comment: [Fortune Cookieはこれ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC)のことです。ちょとした気の利いたことが書かれた紙片がクッキーの中に入っています。米国の中華料理店に行くと支払い時に伝票と共に出てきます。Unixのfortune cookieはここから来ています。

Answer (score 4):

[Lynx](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%96%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B6)) の開発者の一人であり、Netscape 在籍中に cookie を考案した [ルー・モントゥリ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A5%E3%83%AA)氏 が自身のブログ [The irregular musings of Lou Montulli: The reasoning behind Web Cookies](http://www.montulli-blog.com/2013/05/the-reasoning-behind-web-cookies.html) で cookie の由来に言及しています。

> The name
>
> I had heard the term "magic cookie" from an operating systems course from college. The term has a somewhat similar meaning to the way Web Cookies worked and I liked the term "cookies" for aesthetic reasons. Cookies was the first thing I came up with and the name stuck.

そのブログ上で、彼が大学時代にOSの授業で聞いた [magic cookie](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/M/magic-cookie.html) が由来であることが明言されています。

Comment: これは質問の本文にあるように、明らかだと思います。magic cookieの由来が質問では？ウェブが発明される前ならcookieと言えばX端末のMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1が真っ先に思い浮かぶ感じでした。